# Querying Firebase with Inequalities on Multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

```
const Fiis = async () => {
    const data: any[] = [];

    // Performing a query with inequalities on different fields in Firebase.
    // Goal: Get documents with dividendYield between 8 and 20 and pvp less than or equal to 1.
    // Problem: The current query throws the error "FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'dividendYield' and 'pvp'."

    const q = query(
        collection(db, "fiis"),
        where("dividendYield", ">=", 8),
        where("dividendYield", "<=", 20),
        // The code below is commented out because using it results in the error mentioned above.
        // where("pvp", "<=", 1),
    );

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        data.push(doc.data());
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal />
            <span>{data.length}</span>
            {data.length > 0 && <MyTable data={data} />}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Fiis;
```

I'm using Next.js with the latest version that allows async functions, and I'm trying to perform a query on Firebase. I need to retrieve documents with the "dividendYield" field having values between 8 and 20 and, at the same time, the "pvp" field with a value less than or equal to 1.

However, when I add the second condition in the code (as shown in the code above), I receive the following error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'dividendYield' and 'pvp'.

How can I perform this query using inequalities on different fields in the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says and as is also mentioned in the documentation on Firestore's [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So you can't perform a range or inequality filter on two conditions in a query to Firestore.

Two workarounds:

- Perform one equality in the query, and perform the rest of the filtering in your application code. This means you'll be reading more data than needed, so you'll want to use the filter that disqualifies most of the data in the call to the database.
- Add a single field with the two values concatenated, and then perform an inequality on that. This is actually quite common when working with NoSQL databases, where we often change/augment our data model for the use-cases of our app. Here the trade-off becomes that you increase your document size and associated cost, but don't hav to read too many documents from the database anymore.